# Finder showing inconsistent sizes

Tags: macos, finder, mojave, storage

On Mojave macOS, Finder here says that I am using 72 gigs of space.
[image]

But when I open my HD it all adds up to about 42 gigs. Which is size of the system folder as shown in About This Mac, however, here the system folder holds 10 gigs.
[image]

Here's what it shows when I press manage in about this mac> storage.
[image]

So how should I fix this? I don't even have 72 gigs worth of stuff on my mac to begin with. Time machine has also been disabled so there are no time machine backups at the moment.

Comment: All you say could be true and no issues at all. The filesystem isn’t as simple as it once was with sparse files and snapshots. Do you have a specific issue or just worried you have to dig deeper to determine allocation now?

Comment: I just want to reclaim the lost storage space. Why is the system folder so big?

Comment: The system folder isn’t big. Everything else the about this Mac classifies as system is. It’s caches, metadata. Setting up time machine should let the system expire snapshots sooner, to be honest.

Comment: How big is your disk, how much space is currently free?

Comment: 128 gb. total free is 57 gb

Comment: there isn't anything large in caches and meta data.

Comment: @bmike, but would you have 42GB of system files? I've been running my MBP since 2013 upgrading the OS throughout and my system file size is less than 15GB? Caches and data wouldn't take that much surely? Everytime I've emptied system cache it would be a few GBs

Comment: @Muhammad, do you have Xcode developer tools installed, iMovie, Garageband, etc? These have additional files which may be filed under system? If you don't use those apps, you could potentially un-install them and save some storage space. Check application support files for those apps as some of their files can be saved in `~/Library/Application Support` and `/Library/Application Support`

Comment: I don't have that much system files. Even finder says its 10 gb then what's wrong with about this mac?

Comment: Just for some perspective - my System shows as 195GB. As I have more than enough storage for that not to be a worry… it isn't a worry ;) This entire issue stems from everybody wanting SSDs, yet SSDs were expensive, so all the laptop manufacturers put teeny 128GB drives in everything. There are now millions if not hundreds of millions of people who constantly have to worry about a few GB here & there, so much that it consumes them almost more than it consumes disk space.